# How to fix the css range slider bug in mozilla?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a custom range slider, everything is fine in chrome and safari, but when I open the mozilla I see a double slider line, how do I fix this bug?

see the last slider
[Link](https://custom-vue-range-slider.netlify.app/)

**Chrome**

[image]

**mozilla**

[image: MOZILA]

Comment: Please put enough code into  your question so we can reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It seems likely that you have not put the correct CSS for styling a range slider in Firefox e.g. -moz-range-thumb.